# Does sparks foreachPartition run on the driver or on the worker?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

It is unclear from documentation where exactly does the lambda given to the foreachpartition run- on the driver or on the worker?

Comment: Can you post a link to documentation with this statement about _enough memory on driver_?

Comment: @Vladislav Varslavans, I confused with toLocalIterator. Amended the text of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as `foreach()` `foreachPartition()` is executed on workers. There is no reason to transfer data to driver to process it.

```
rdd.foreachPartition { rddpartition =>
    val thinUrl = "some jdbc url"
    val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(thinUrl)
    rddpartition.foreach { record =>
        conn.createStatement().execute("some statement" )
    }
    conn.commit()
}
```

Comment: But many times, the example given is where we want to conserve db connections. So we batch the requests using foreachpartition. But the dbconnection object is not serializable, so how would it work?

Comment: You should create db connection object **inside** function you pass to `foreachPartition()` function. You can see an example [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/85406/spark-how-to-make-calls-to-database-using-foreachp.html). This way you will not need to serialize db connection since it will be created on the worker and it will be used only there.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Inside a foreachPartition loop when I print the executorId, it always shows Driver (SparkEnv.get().executorId() -> always displays Driver). How do e get the executorId and see where each executes?